# Adding a Mask in TensorFlow for training/inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, masking

I am using `tf.contrib.slim` to train and evaluate state-of-the-art CNNs. I was wondering if there is a method that I can use `tf.select` or `tf.where` to create a mask to ignore certain weights' computation during training (or even inference) certain. Say, I would like to ignore the weights having value 0 and keep up training my model. Is it possible?

Any suggestions/codes would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the two questions aren't strictly related to each other, maybe you will have better luck in getting a reply if you split this post into two separate posts.

Comment: OK. @ninjin. will do